# How can I get the date and time a C++ file was compiled?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Is there any way to use the date and time a C++ source file was compiled so it can be used in the code, e.g.:

```
cout << "this file was compiled on " << CompileDate << " at " << CompileTime" << endl;
```

How can I calculate `CompileDate` and `CompileTime`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using gcc preprocessor then you will find what you are looking for in the **TIME** and **DATE** macros

> **DATE** The date of translation of the source file (a character string literal of the form "Mmm dd yyyy", where the names of the months are the same as those generated by the asctime function, and the first character of dd is a space character if the value is less than 10). If the date of translation is not available, an implementation-defined valid date is supplied.
>
> **TIME** The time of translation of the source file (a character string literal of the form "hh:mm:ss" as in the time generated by the asctime function). If the time of translation is not available, an implementation-defined valid time is supplied.

```
cout << __DATE__ << endl;
cout << __TIME__ << endl;
```

will print out the compile date and time.